# CoreData save does no persist over app lifestyle

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4

I got a strange issue. I am inserting a new object into my Core Data database.
I can make request over all my datas but when I close the application and launch it again all my datas are gone ... With iPhone 0S 3 I haven't got this problem, but now with iOS 4 ...
Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer of Marcus S. Zarra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106732/ios-4-core-data-any-changes-with-multitasking) probably is a good hint. iOS4 changed a lot because of multitasking.

> For a start, take everything you do in
>   -applicationWillTerminate: and copy it also into
>   -applicationDidEnterBackground:. See if that helps. – Thomas Müller Jun 28
>   at 23:16